# How can I convert a method into a generic method?

Tags: java, generics, gwt

I have the following method:

```
public Push getPush() {
    Push plugin;
    String pluginName = PGPluginNames.PUSH;
    if (!isPluginInitialized(pluginName)) {
        plugin = (Push) GWT.create(Push.class);
        plugin.initialize();
        phoneGap.loadPlugin(pluginName, plugin);
        initializedPlugins.add(pluginName);
    }
    else {
        plugin = (Push) phoneGap.getPluginById(pluginName);
    }
    return plugin;
}
```

I want to transfer this method into a generic method. I tried the following:

```
public <T extends PhoneGapPlugin> T getType(T t, String pluginName) {
    T plugin = null;
    if (!isPluginInitialized(pluginName)) {
        plugin = (T) GWT.create(t.getClass());
        plugin.initialize();
        phoneGap.loadPlugin(pluginName, plugin);
        initializedPlugins.add(pluginName);
    }
    else {
        plugin = (T) phoneGap.getPluginById(pluginName);
    }
    return plugin;
}
```

This gives a compiler error.

```
Only class literals may be used as arguments to GWT.create()
```

I do not see how I get the class literal of T because I cannot do `T.class GWT.create()` will throw an error.

Is there any way to fix that?

Edit:

I also tried the following code:

```
public <T extends PhoneGapPlugin> T getType(Class<T> classLiteral, String pluginName) {
    T plugin = null;
    if (!isPluginInitialized(pluginName)) {
        plugin = (T) GWT.create(classLiteral);
        plugin.initialize();
        phoneGap.loadPlugin(pluginName, plugin);
        initializedPlugins.add(pluginName);
    }
    else {
        plugin = (T) phoneGap.getPluginById(pluginName);
    }
    return plugin;
}
```

It gives the error:

```
Only class literals may be used as arguments to GWT.create()
```

And also the Warning to the cast:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object.
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Constraints of the Java language

You can't get the class literal of `T`. You need to pass a `Class<T>` along as argument to your method.

You can compare it with the `EnumMap` constructor for instance, it needs the class literal, and since it can't deduce it from the type parameter, the constructor looks as follots:

```
public EnumMap(Class<K> keyType)
```

### Constraints of GWT and the create method

This method is special in the sense that the compiler must be able to determine the requested type *at compile time*. Had it been a parameter to the method, the compiler can't tell what that argument will be passed to your generic method at runtime. The [Javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#create%28java.lang.Class%29) for the method says this explicitly:

> The argument to `create(Class)` *must* be a class literal because the Production Mode compiler must be able to statically determine the requested type at compile-time. This can be tricky because using a Class variable may appear to work correctly in Development Mode.

In other words, you're out of luck. You can't put anything but class literals, i.e. `Push.class` as argument to GWT.create.

Comment: Answer updated. What you want to do can't be done with GWT.create.